# Chrome: turn off dark mode during opening http / https links

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

I am using Chrome in Windows 10 and disabled dark mode with appending `--disable-features=DarkMode` to the shortcut.
But it is still running in a dark mode when I'm opening link `http` or `https`, for example, from Outlook.

Where in the registry it have to be added `--disable-features=DarkMode` for disabling this terrible dark mode in the Chrome browser?

Or, please advice any other workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Go to chrome://flags

2- In Search Input Type dark

3- Choose "Force Dark Mode for Web Contents"

4- Disable It.[image]

5- ReLunch your Browser